# How to include a count from a Parse class in TableViewController that isn't the main query table, using Swift?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to display a tableview with two pieces of information: the name of a place (in code called a "candidate") and the # of votes it has received. I'm getting these two pieces of information from two different classes, stored on Parse.

I can get the name of the place just fine - it's data stored in the main table I'm querying in the queryForTable() function and displaying using the tableView(tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: object:) function:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class CategoryViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {
var currentObject : PFObject?
var candidates: Array<AnyObject>?

override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.parseClassName = "CategoryCandidates"
    self.textKey = "candidateTitle"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false
}

override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    var categoryCandidates = PFQuery(className: "CategoryCandidates")
    categoryCandidates.whereKey("categoryID", equalTo: currentObject!)

    return categoryCandidates
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> CandidateTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CandidateTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = CandidateTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    cell?.voteButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
    if let candidateTitle = object?["candidateTitle"] as? String {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = candidateTitle
    }

    return cell
}
```

For the # of votes, I have a separate table on Parse (called "CandidateVotes") which has a single row that represents each vote on the "candidate". What I would like to do is do a count on the rows in the CandidateVotes table that have a pointer to a given "candidate".

But I don't know how to do that as part of the queryForTable() function so that the information is displayed together on the tableview.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common scenario that people run into when setting up a list view like this. Instead of trying to come up with a complicated query that returns the data you need, I would suggest modeling your schema in a way that makes it possible to obtain this data using the simplest query.

You could achieve this in this case by ensuring the candidate votes data is also tracked in your `CategoryCandidates` table. Your `cellForRow[...]` method would then be able to get this information from the key:

```
 if let candidateVotesTotal = object?["candidateVotesTotal"] as? Number {
     cell?.someTextLabel?.text = candidateVotesTotal
 }
```

You can make sure `"candidateVotesTotal"` tracks this data by using a After Cloud Function on your `CandidateVotes` class that takes care of updating all the relevant `CategoryCandidates` objects whenever a new vote is recorded.

Comment: Thanks much for the answer, Hector - I'll look into After Cloud Functions and try that out. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again, Hector. I've gotten Cloud Code setup, added a votes total column to my candidates table - so that makes sense to me as a solution. I'm having an error though with my aftersave function - if you have a chance, would really love your thoughts - I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405297/aftersave-cloud-function-for-parse-that-increments-value-in-another-data-table