# Aftersave Cloud Function for Parse that increments value in another data table?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm having trouble getting my aftersave cloud function to increment a value in another data table. The Parse documentation is a bit confusing on this front.

I have a table called "CandidateVotes" that stores a row for each vote on a "candidate" - and when a new vote row is saved, I would like to increment the total votes count stored in a different table called "CategoryCandidates" which has a row for each "candidate".

So the relevant information:

- Votes table is called "CandidateVotes"
- Candidates table is called "CategoryCandidates"
- Total votes count column in CategoryCandidates table is called "votes"

Here's my Parse aftersave cloud function:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("CandidateVotes", function(request) {
  query = new Parse.Query("CategoryCandidates");
  query.get(request.object.get("CategoryCandidates").objectID, {
    success: function(candidate) {
      candidate.increment("votes");
      candidate.save();
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.error("Got an error" + error.code + " : " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

When a new vote is saved, this is the error that I'm getting in my cloud code logs:

```
E2015-09-04T15:49:23.553Z]v9 after_save triggered for CandidateVotes as master:
  Input: {"object":{"candidateID":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"CategoryCandidates","objectId":"HOBbNA690z"},"createdAt":"2015-09-04T15:49:09.216Z","objectId":"RlmvJjG04t","updatedAt":"2015-09-04T15:49:23.549Z","userID":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"7YfU2ETvb3"}}}
  Result: TypeError: Cannot read property 'objectID' of undefined
    at main.js:6:53
```

The Parse documentation (https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-aftersave-triggers) has an example, but it's unclear to me what the lowercase "post" is referring to in their data schema. I'm also not well-versed in JS so might be making a rookie mistake there.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can definitely be a bit of a head-scratcher to debug cloud code but you were nearly there. You want to access the objectId of the "CategoryCandidates" class pointer, which you are currently using `request.object.get("CategoryCandidates").objectID` to do.

The problem is, when you look at the log for the input to your afterSave, the name of the pointer is "candidateID", not "CategoryCandidates".

Try using `request.object.get("candidateID").objectID`

Cheers,
Russell

Comment: Thanks very much, Russel.  

With that fix, I'm now getting this error:  

    E2015-09-04T21:37:28.049Z]v10 after_save triggered for CandidateVotes for user 7YfU2ETvb3:  

    Input: {"object":{"candidateID":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"CategoryCandidates","objectId":"3C5KPJP3fh"},"createdAt":"2015-09-04T21:37:28.045Z","objectId":"tHSUbMMBiZ","updatedAt":"2015-09-04T21:37:28.045Z","userID":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"7YfU2ETvb3"}}}  

   Result: TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of null
    at Object.query.get.error (main.js:12:43)
    ...  


Any thoughts?

Comment: For the above comment, I was getting that error for the code in my error clause - when I removed it, it went away. Was still having trouble - but resolved it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409920/parse-aftersave-cloud-function-returns-a-success-result-but-doesnt-execute-succ - thanks again for the help!